# Mount two nfs's shares from different storage over the same directory on linux

Tags: linux, nfs, cluster, mount

I have a set of 4 Linux web servers on cluster all of them have the same mount point:

```
/folder
```

This `/folder` is a NFS mount share over a NAS but is full and no more luns/disk are available to expand the NFS. I have another NAS with enough space to solve the problem, but a software developed in house search for JPG files over the `/folder`. I want to know if is possible to mount another NFS share from the other NAS to the same directory to have more space? No matter that the new path to write files is `/folder/newshare`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want do do can be achieved precisely with [overlayfs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt). With it you can take your /full dir and another /notfull dir and mount them at /third-dir.

Reads will seek through the /notfull into the /full and writes will go to a third dir.

Have a look at the docs, remount the full dir away from the target name and then use overlayfs to recreate the intended target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I take this option as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to expand the space by mounting them both on `/folder` if that's what you want.  If you want to create another directory like `/folder/newshare` like you said, you should be able to mount another NFS share there to make it seem like there's more space under `/folder`.  I just confirmed that I could create a mount point for a NFS share inside another NFS share, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try and coming back to update.

Comment: This option works too, but the developers have to make changes into the code, thanks for your answer.